# Are there usability advantages to macOS's built-in RAID?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, backup, disk-utility, raid

There is no need for external disk enclosures (whether NAS or not) to have RAID.

MacOS supports software-based RAID
([striped/mirrored/concatenated](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/disk-utility/dskua23150fd/mac)).

Of the two options (RAID in the OS or outside) I'd normally say there is no need to load the OS with more work. If RAID is external and in hardware, the combined system will be faster, but this doesn't say anything about usability—before or after the failure of a disk, and especially with third-party products (Apple anyway bailed out from Time Capsule-like products) that are meant for either Mac or PC.

Are there usability advantages to macOS's built-in RAID?

##### (update)

It can be difficult to answer a general question, so let me mention a concrete scenario.

I am offloading my photo and music collection to external drives; both collections are still tiny (~250GB each, but 4k video is still young, and internal storage on MacBook Pro won't keep up).

I have two Apple AirPort Time Capsules, and I use both for Time Capsule (one is redundant backup) of my main disk on a Macbook Pro.

###### Solution 1: Software RAID

I would connect two 3.5" 4TB hard disks, one each to the USB port on each AirPort Time Capsule—leaving the Time Machine disks alone.

Then I would configure the two new disks as RAID-1 (redundant; one mirror copy of the other).

###### Solution 2: No RAID; use `rsync`

I would still connect the two disks to the two AirPort TCs, but one would be a master, and the other a copy, with `rsync` running nightly to make a mirror copy.

###### Solution 3: Hardware RAID

I would install two disks in a RAID, likely as NAS, duplicating the AirPort TCs. I would keep the AirPort TCs for backup, and use the hardware RAID for photos+music.

Which solution would you use? Is there any advantage to 3 over 1 besides speed? Is there a usability advantage to 1 over 3, if/when a disk fails? Suppose I'm willing to take the risk of losing one day's worth of photos or music, is there anything else that's otherwise wrong with Solution 2 (which is the simplest)?

Comment: What Mac are you thinking of? This is easy & stable in a Mac Pro, no accidental disconnects because you can get 6 drives in one before having to resort to PCIe cards. With anything else, you're hanging a bunch of externals off it, no matter how they're configured, there can be accidents.

Comment: @Tetsujin I made the question much more specific. Could you take another look? I am using an Intel MacBook Pro.

Comment: The AirPort Time Capsule doesn't support RAID at all. I'd be more inclined to transfer to a single drive, also included in Time Machine, & use Backblaze as the 'belt & braces'. That gives you one on-site, & one off-site for if the house burns down… & no delicate RAID structure to worry about.

Comment: @Tetsujin Time Capsule doesn't support RAID. It may well be possible, however, to connect Disk #1 to Time Capsule #1; Disk #2 to Time Capsule #2; and use Disk Utility to set them up as RAID from software.

Comment: Time Capsule doesn't support RAID… so it won't let you. Aside from that, trying to RAID two external devices over Ethernet hanging off two different hosts is simply a terrible idea, even if you could get it working. Just connect two Time Machine drives. It will use them both.